# What generic/dynamic collection to use? (design issue)

Tags: c#

We are creating a simple but improved billing solution. Since we have to use different providers based on a number of reasons that is of no importance right now I was thinking of what would be the best way to handle this. The different providers might have a key and a value. I can store the value as object but then I need to store the type as well. I was thinking of creating a hmm let's call it Tuple class:

```
public class Tuple<TType, TValue>
{
    public TType Type { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can use this for storing the type reference but it I have a feeling something is missing. To use this with a lookup collection like dictionary I could:

```
public IDictionary<string, Tuple<Type, object>> TechnicalDetails = 
  new Dictionary<string, Tuple<Type, object>>
```

Suggestions for improvement? There has got to be a better way? :)

Comment: The question is really too generic for anyone to offer reasonable solutions. What are you trying to accomplish with your choice of data structure? Is the point to be able to choose a provider based on its identifier? If you can clarify what you are trying to accomplish it will be easier to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Let's say I have two different providers. One of the providers have 3 unique key/value pairs each value can be of a different type. The second provider has 5 unique key/value pairs where each value can be of any given type. All the keys are different but I want to handle them in a generic way.

Comment: What is the type used for? Do you need to instantiate it? Where does it come from? Is it loaded from a database? Are you already using dependency injection? What are you actually doing?? Try to explain what you are doing in a programming point of view, omitting project specific stuff.

Comment: I created a Tuple, Triple and so on and so forth. I have been reusing it for a million other things so it was well invested time. I kind of like this but the methods returning the tuples and triples need to be documented well with what First, Second, Third and Forth values actually contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this, I tend to write a class to contain/hide the data structure, and to provide methods and properties which abstract away the details of the data structure, in this case, your `Dictionary<string, Tuple<Type, object>>`.

Methods like Find( ), Get( ), Add( ), Remove( ) etc, are easy to add since the data structure itself already has similar methods.

Answer (score 1):

how many items are you going to store in the dictionary? a [hybrid dictonary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.hybriddictionary.aspx) might offer better performance?

Comment: This I did not know I will however have a need to store what type the value is as well. It's not going to be that many items. Maximum 6-7 pairs per entity and around 100 000 entities.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to represent any instance.

```
Dictionary<string, XElement>
```